# android application runs in background

Tags: android, service

Not sure if possible, but is there a way to have an application running in the background and that will work with other applications?
For example - can I have an application that add gesture shortcuts (for example for paste) and it will work with ANY application I run?
Kind of a service running in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is excatly that kind of thing. And it's called... [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

There are many good tutorials out there on this topic, like [this one](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html).

Also you might want to check the Android resources on [Gestures](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html).

Comment: A Service will not be able to "add gesture shortcuts".

Comment: You could store the gestures within a service and request it's data from the app you are running. Or you could check out Android's own Gesture stuff and GestureOverlayView described here http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

Comment: `GestureOverlayView` requires a UI; services do not have UIs.

Comment: True, but the data they provide is generally accessed by apps that do have UI's.